# jQuery validation: Initial/On the fly validation of checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jquery validation plugin: [jQuery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org). Now, I have this snippet with a simple validation method which is used to verify the number of checked  checkboxes based on a given parameter

```
$.validator.methods.cbMinRequired = function (value, element, param) {
  return $(element).parent().find(":checked").length >= param;
};

$(function () {
    // validate the comment form when it is submitted
    $("#myform").validate({
        keyup: true,
        keypress: true,
        click: true,
        change: true,
        debug: true,
        errorClass: "invalid",
        rules: {
            mycheckboxes: {
                cbMinRequired: 1
            }
        }
    });
  });
```

Check out my Fiddle: [jsFiddle checkbox vaidation example](http://jsfiddle.net/sVwFb/)

As you can see, I have a problem.

I have to validate the form by triggering "submit" first. But I want to validate it after load. There is no option to trigger the submit initially as I think, since at the end I want to trigger a 'save action' with this button which shouldn't be invoked after page load.

Any kind of ideas how to cope with this?

Comment: There are no such options for this plugin called `keyup`, `keypress`, `click`, or `change`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#myform").validate({
        keyup: true,
        keypress: true,
        click: true,
        change: true,
        debug: true,
        errorClass: "invalid",
        rules: {
            mycheckboxes: {
                cbMinRequired: 1
            }
        }
    });
});
```

There is a major issue with your code:  **[There are no such options for this plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) called `keyup`, `keypress`, `click`, or `change`.**  They are called `onkeyup`, `onfocusout`, `onclick`, and `onsubmit` and they are already "true" by default... they cannot be set to `true` without breaking the plugin.  You can only set them to `false` to disable, or set them to a custom function.

Then you can programatically trigger a validation test at any time you wish by using [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid).

```
$("#myform").valid();
```

This will trigger validation on page load...

```
$(function () {

    $("#myform").validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // options
    });

    $("#myform").valid(); // trigger validation on page load

});
```

**Your DEMO updated**:  http://jsfiddle.net/sVwFb/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can call the [`.valid()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) method to trigger a validation without submitting.

```
if (!$("#myform").valid()) {
    // Complain
}
```

See my version of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/sVwFb/3/), it displays the validation message when the page loads.

Comment: It doesn't work in my case: I want to see the error messages. Its so strange: a simple range input field is checked on the fly but first, after losing one times the focus. It doesn't need submit then. Checkboxes do need that action. It makes the plugin needless in my case. Really bad :/

Comment: Works for me, if I understand what you want. See my fiddle.

Comment: Another (stupid) issue was that I've tried to trigger it on this way: $("#myform").validate({ ... }).valid() ... don't try it! :) If I separate the calls, it works fine

Comment: Yeah, it looks like he didn't code it properly so that it can be chained. `.validate()` returns a validator object, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score -1):

Barman is right, but if you want to submit onload and handle the submission on the second submit, you can use a flag variable and submit.

```
$('#myform').submit();
submitEnabled = true;
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/sVwFb/1/) the jsFiddle updated.