# Thymeleaf - Form validation and error messages

Tags: html, thymeleaf

once we type in the text box & **move out from the text box**, Is that possible to show an validation **error messages dynamically**.
Now It's able show the validation error messages when we submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

Using only Thymeleaf is impossible, because field content is validated on server side (after form submission). You can validate some types of content in html5 [like here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/). Another, more complicated but also more powerful way is to use AngularJS([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581439/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angular-js-form)) or JQuery([another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575980/jquery-validation-initial-on-the-fly-validation-of-checkbox))

HTH